# ES6 call to static method throwing an error

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I've got the following class in Javascript:

cart.js

```
class Cart{

    static addItem(data, beforeSendCallback=null, successCallback=null, errorCallback=null) {
        const emptyCallback = ()=>{}
        if(data){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/orders/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                beforeSend: beforeSendCallback == null ? emptyCallback : beforeSendCallback,
                success: successCallback == null ? emptyCallback : successCallback,
                error: errorCallback == null ? emptyCallback : errorCallback,
                dataType: 'json'
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in a different file I've got:

item.js

```
...
function addItemToCart(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let data = {
        'itemId': $('#item_id').val(),
        'type': $('#item_type').val(),
        'quantity': $('#quantity').val(),
        'stock': $('#in_stock').val(),
        'price': $('#item_price').val()
    }

    if (data.stock != 2) {
        Cart.addItem(data, disableAddToCartBtn(true), disableAddToCartBtn(false))
    }
}
...
```

When `add-cart-btn` is pressed then this function is executed but I'm getting an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Cart is not defined,
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.addItemToCart (item.js:20)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5206)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:5014)

These two files are being added to `app.js` which is in charge of processing them via webpack:

```
require('./core/cart')
require('./item')
```

Since I'm requiring `./core/cart` first I assumed its content would be available for `./item`, am I wrong?

Comment: Your error indicates that it's being run in the browser, but you give an example using `require()`, which AFAIK isn't supported in any browser. There's probably quite a bit of missing information here. I assume you're using a bundler? More details would definitely help.

Comment: Every module has its own scope. You should export the necessary classes (with `module.exports`) and take advantage of the return value of `require`.

Comment: a simple fix is `window.Cart = Cart` inside `cart.js` if you are in browser

Comment: @appleapple Polluting the global namespace should be avoided especially if you're already in a module environment - the solution is to use the module environment, not to try to work around it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I would say class can safely stay inside global space. `const Cart = require('./core/cart');` do the same thing, just inside different space.

Comment: @appleapple What if your script has a few classes, and another script has a few classes, and yet another script on the page has a few classes? Then the global namespace is completely polluted.

Comment: @CertainPerformance it's called `global namespace` instead of `undefined` because it's a namespace, one should use it when appropriate. (like use inline event handler)

Comment: @appleapple Inline event handlers are essentially `eval` inside HTML markup - they're bad practice and result in poorly factored, hard-to-manage code. Seriously consider attaching your events with JavaScript, instead.

Comment: @CertainPerformance it's just an example, and I don't hate `eval`, neither Inline event handlers. I like clean code, not separated code. I think we need to agree to disagree here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try assigning the imported cart to a variable:

`const Cart = require('./core/cart');`

and make sure you export the cart in cart.js:

`module.exports = class Cart {`

Comment: It worked! Thanks. If you don't mind, why does it need to be exported? I mean, by requiring it in app.js is not supposed to 'paste' its content into that file therefore the class can be referenced from down below?

Comment: No, modules provide a *convenient way of managing dependencies* (among other things) - they don't automatically make everything global, that would defeat the whole purpose. Explicitly defining what each module exports and what each module imports is what makes writing and debugging larger scripts manageable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to export the `Cart` class in `cart.js`, then import and actually **assign** it to a variable where you want to use it. In `cart.js`:

```
// ....
module.exports = Cart;
```

Then in whatever module you want to use `Cart`:

```
const Cart = require('./core/cart');
// use the `Cart` class.
```